# Battery Popup at 25%

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, battery, popup

I seem to have run into a bit of a challenge on one of our Android/Samsung devices...

On the device, regardless of what's open, when the battery reaches 25% on discharge, the below screen pops up and covers the entire screen, with MUCH difficulty to get rid of. I've tried to trace it to a certain app, but was unsuccessful in doing so.

[image: Android Popup]

Can someone perhaps help with some advice on this, on how to get rid of it?

Comment: I just got this out of the blue as well, I had to soft reset to get rid of the popup. I can't trace it back to any setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the Peel Remote app. I deleted this app and it stopped.

Comment: I trust you, but we'll see... My phone is fully charged atm

Comment: Can confirm that this works. My popup is no more!

Comment: Confirmed again, S5. The popup is no longer a problem. Can't believe Peel shows system-like notifications. It is also against the developer policies, no app can show system-like notifications.

Comment: I started thinking it was an actual system popup. It  cannot be dismissed and often pops up every 2%. It is draining my battery telling me to save battery power :/ This has been reproduced on 2 samsung devices (S5 and S6 Edge), peel was the cause both times

Comment: I did visited the Settings => Device => Sounds and notifications => App Notifications => Peel Remote
Over there, I unchecked the Block. It now does not shows the notifications as shown in the image above.
Hence it resolved issue on my phone by keeping the application intact. [No need to uninstall/disable the app]

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a **default setting popup** which shows when your battery level reaches to a preset value of 25%. You can change these in **Settings->Battery->BatterySaver** option where you can either set the level to show the popup at 15% or 10% or you can turn it off by setting the `turn on automatically` option to NEVER.

Answer (score 1):

My only fix is to plug my phone in... It instantly goes away at that point.
Though I'd rather it not happen in the first place. It's very intrusive.