# Battery Popup at 25% english with system in spanish. Possible malware?

Tags: settings, battery, malware, 7.0-nougat, popup

First of all, I know this question is duplicated, (this is the original question: [Battery Popup at 25%](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174631/battery-popup-at-25) ) but I can't comment or add any reply and I have some information that could be useful to identify the problem.

This is the Pop-Up:

[image: Weird Pop-up]

The original answer states that it can be a default system pop up, but my system is in spanish and the pop up is in english. The pop up stays on top of the screen and there is no way to hide it, not even by the recent apps button nor the home button. Even locking the screen keeps the pop up visible. The only way I found to get rid of this is with a soft reset. In fact, the pop up looks completly different from the system default notification shown with the battery at 15%

My device is a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android Nougat (7.0)

I think it can be some kind of malware, but I've run some security apps (AVG, Dr.Web, ESET) and none of them found anything.

I've not installed any apps recently and nothing outside Google Play

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely malware related! When this happened first? Did you install some apps? Note that not all malware can be detected! You need to check deeper, manually or using adb

Comment: It happened today, while writing a whatsapp, but I believe it was when the battery reached 25%. I have not installed anything recently and all my apps are from the Play Store

Comment: Does any notification comes along? Or any icon

Comment: No, there is no icon or any other notification. It just shows the pop up covering more than the half of the screen, and stays there no matter what I do, except the soft reset.

Comment: I'd suggest you do some investigations inside your app list: downloaded apps, all apps and see if you can find any unusual app

Comment: Besides, some malwares always make use of your data bandwidth in the background as they download files without you notice. What does "Data usage" report? Do you see any unusual data consumption by an unknown app?

Comment: I would considering what could be the possible gain from an attacker's point of view. Did you try tapping on any of the suggested settings, OP?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its just a malfunctioning battery optimization tool. About half of the time i got this it had a dismiss option but other times i couldn't do anything with my phone until I plugged it in. Try changing the following settings:

Settings > battery > advanced settings and turn off the app power monitor.

I haven't seen the pop-up since yesterday morning when I did changed them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to disable or roll back the Peel Smart Remote Application that Android pre-installed. I have just confirmed it twice. We can't uninstall without rooting. The application manager settings is not followed by Peel Smart Remote and the settings in the application itself have a 30 day timeout. Be sure to not update it in either case as it can even enable it.

---

Additional Information, Peel Remote Version 9.8.3.6 was the one causing problems on my Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 7.0, AT&T) and S5 (Android 6.0.1, Verizon). I informed Samsung as the two phones would suggest, but they suggested a common application.

Answer (score -1):

I have samsung S6 ... try this:

Peel remote >> Setting >> Notification >> Battery saver alert >> OFF